# .htaccess to fix a bad URL (e.g., https://example.com/upload/https://cloudinary.com/img.jpg) containing a path with a concatenated or appended URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cloudinary

I just upgraded the Wordpress Cloudinary plugin and it ended up breaking the featured images URLs.

Here's an example of with happened. Image URLs changes from

`https://res.cloudinary.com/xyz/image/upload/v0000000000/image.jpg` to

`https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/https://res.cloudinary.com/xyz/image/upload/v0000000000/image.jpg`

Is it possible to use .htaccess to temporarily redirect these bad URLs to good URLs?

For example something like this:

`RedirectMatch 302 /wp-content/uploads/https://res.cloudinary.com/xyz/(.*) https:/res.cloudinary.com/lax/$1`

Comment: Should be possible, yes, but I’m not sure RedirectMatch is the best way to go about this. I’d try a RewriteRule instead, `RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/https://res.cloudinary.com/(.*) https://res.cloudinary.com/$1 [R=302]` Make sure to place it above the default WP rewriting.

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately that didn't work. I'm guessing that it doesn't like the "/https://" but don't know how to confirm it.

Comment: According to https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ it should work, but it is always a bit troublesome to match all the request conditions and rewriting setup in there exactly. Where did you place this, in the context of the existing WP rewriting? In theory, the `/https://` should not be a problem. Can you show what the actual image element `src` attribute contains, taken from the actual HTML source code (not DOM inspector view)? Maybe WP / the plugin has applied some additional URL encoding or sth. like that.

Comment: What WP version are you using? Were your images synched?

Comment: @CBroe When the inspected URL is entered into the browser it does change in that the double /https:// turns to a single /https:/ and I've accounted for that by applying a rule for both cases. (e.g., .../wp-content/uploads/https:/res.cloudinary.com/...)

Comment: @Michalk WP V5.4 and yes the images are synched and worked before the Cloudinary plugin update.

Comment: @CBroe Hi, I'm working at Cloudinary and currently, we have a system incident with our WP plugin. please check our status page:https://status.cloudinary.com for updates.